# pgrouting createTopology error: column source not found!

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I tried to create a topology, this is the first steps in pgrouting.

I executed
`select pgr_createTopology('public.line_shapefile', 0.00001, 'geom', 'id');`

It returned the following error. seems like there are no column "source" which I don't know what value I should put in.

```
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  pgr_createTopology('public.line_shapefile', 1e-05, 'geom', 'id', 'source', 'target', rows_where := 'true', clean := f)
NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait .....
NOTICE:  ----> PGR ERROR in pgr_createTopology: Column source not found
HINT:    ----> Check your column name
NOTICE:  Unexpected error raise_exception
```

I tried reading the documentation on `pg_createTopology` and I still don't understand what `source` or `target` is. [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/236581/159263) gives the clue but I do not now how to create the SQL statement as I am very much new to PostGIS/pgrouting/SQL.

my column names for the table (where the `geom` stores the geometry information):

```
id
geom
name
path
layer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of pg_routing is not always clear.

You need to modify the table that contains your paths to add a *source* and a *target* columns *before* calling the pgr_createTopology function (see  [this workshop](https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.4.11/en/chapters/topology.html#create-a-routing-network-topology)). The pgr_createTopology function will fill the *source* and *target* columns.

Here is the code to use :

```
-- Add the needed columns
ALTER TABLE public.line_shapefile ADD COLUMN "source" integer;
ALTER TABLE public.line_shapefile ADD COLUMN "target" integer;

-- Run topology function
select pgr_createTopology('public.line_shapefile', 0.00001, 'geom', 'id');
```

Comment: thanks, this works. so simply add integer column with name 'source' and 'target'!